# Total bound charge in dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, polarization

We know that the total bound charge in a dielectric is zero. The surface and volume bound charges in a dielectric due to polarization vector $\mathbf{P}$ is given by $\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$.

Now, if $\mathbf{P}$ is proportional to $\mathbf{r}/r$, then $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}$ is always zero, which means that volume bound charge density is zero. But the total surface charge is not zero. For example, a thick dielectric spherical shell with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$, and if $\mathbf{P}$ is proportional to $\mathbf{r}/r$, then total bound charge $4\pi P(b^2-a^2)$ is not equal to zero!

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, please consider writing descriptive question titles with appropriate punctuation, grammar, and formatting. See this meta post: [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413).

Comment: @Chair: I have re-typed the question. This doesn't appear to be a homework-like question.

Comment: @user7777777 My interpretation is that it was a check-my-work question, though it is in a bit of a grey area since it's generalized. Honestly, the absence of a clear question and the reference to an example in a textbook make it seem like OP came to a certain conclusion and is looking for that to be validated.

Comment: actually it is not a check my work question.please see my question carefully i think  something puzzle may appear to you.please give me the actual reason why this happen.

Comment: It is a check-my-work question: you've described an incorrect derivation and asked about why that happens, and the simple answer is that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{P}\neq 0$. That's a mathematical mistake, not a physics concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strength of $P$ is constant, then there is positive divergence, not $0$. If however the divergence is $0$, then the strength of P isn't constant meaning $P(r=a) \cdot 4\pi a^2 = P(r=b) \cdot 4\pi b^2$.

Comment: please explain me if P is a constant then how divergence of P is positive.

Comment: Just plugged in the formula of divergence in spherical coordinates:
$$\nabla \cdot P = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial (r^2 P)}{\partial r} = \frac{2P}{r} > 0 $$

Comment: but i say in my question that P vary like 1/r^2. then the divergence is always zero but the if you calculate surface bound charge it is not equal to zero. please do the surface integral over both surface.

Comment: If $P=\frac{P_0}{r^2} \hat{r}$ then the divergence is 0 but $\iint P\cdot \vec{dA}$ is $- \frac{P_0}{a^2} \cdot 4\pi a^2 +  \frac{P_0}{b^2} \cdot 4\pi b^2 =0$